# How do I render links from a certain section on a Zendesk Help Centre home_page hbs template?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, themes, zendesk

I'm using a customised Zendesk Help Centre theme, and in the `home_page.hbs` template, I want to output the 10 most recent links from a certain **section** (or just as good, with a certain **label**). I can't find anything useful in the Zendesk online docs, including the standard and advanced 'helper' functions. I'd imagine it would look something like:

```
{{#if section.id '12345678' ../has_articles}}
     {{#each articles count=10}}
          <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
     {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Zendesk support offered nothing of use.

Answer (score 1):

Use following format:

```html
{{#each categories}}
  {{#each sections}}
    {{#is id 360001734738}}
      {{#each articles}}
        <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
      {{/each}}
    {{/is}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

As for limiting articles count to 10, currently there is no way to do it with Zendesk helpers parameters, you have use CSS or JS here. Using CSS it would be something like that:

```css
.section .article:nth-child(n+11) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: nice suggestion on the css, ZD is a bit limited in some ways of manipulating the data

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly someone will come in handy

You can use helper `slice` with zendesk

```
    {{#if section.id '12345678' ../has_articles}}
         {{#each (slice articles 0 10)}}
              <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
         {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
```